# My appliances are shocking me...but only me

Tags: wiring

The metal parts of the fridge, stove, and sink are shocking me. However, when my husband touches them, he gets nothing. I've also found that the metal gates and latches leading to the pastures are shocking me--the pasture fences are electrified fencing, but there is no reason the gates should be catching that current, and the fences are definitely grounded. No one else is getting shocked besides me, so I assume I'm somehow a mega-conductor?? Anyone else ever run into this problem? Cooking has become a serious issue...

Comment: Your skin may be particularly conductive, or maybe you wear footwear that's conductive (or don't wear any footwear), which makes you more susceptible to shocks. Do you have high voltage power lines near your house? You may be getting some induced voltage from power lines on the gates and/or fence, but inside the house it sounds like you have a grounding problem. Maybe the house ground system is not connected and something in the house is leaking voltage to what should be "ground", but is now floating.Is it a quick shock like static electricity or does it continue as long as you're touching it?

Comment: This sounds like normal static shock.  Do you live in a dry area?  Wear wool shirts/socks?  Walk around the house in rubber-soled shoes?  When you touch these things for a few seconds without letting go, do you feel only a single shock *(static shock)*, multiple distinct shocks at regular intervals *(electric fencing)*, or a painful numbness that travels quickly up your arm *(leakage from a 120V line)*?

Comment: Hold his one hand and make him touch something with the other. ;)

Comment: Do you wear Crocs (especially lined Crocs)? These types of shoes are very good insulators, which could allow you to build up a voltage potential to ground.   The insulated type are even worse if worn with socks, as simply walking in them is like dragging your feet across a shag carpet.

Comment: Have you checked your fingers for splinters?